# Maven version range queries causes repository query multiple times and fails when updated during build

Tags: pom.xml, maven

Using version ranges in maven, having e.g. [1.0.0, 2.0.0) set for the same artifact name in multiple transient dependencies of a huge dependency tree, maven is going to fetch the latest artifact over and over again, taking some hours due doe many thousand repeated requests for the very same artifact version range.

Most critical: if during the build another user uploads  a newer version, the very same build fetches 2 different versions of that artifact, although the same version range is referred. This results in a build error. It is not expected that maven repeats the very same artifact version range request during the very same build. **If artifact changed meanwhile, the build fails.**

One possible solution could be to run:
mvn versions:resolve-ranges
which replaces the version ranges in the pom.xml's with the concrete version numbers.

However, during evaluation, we could run into the same problem again...

Is there any proper solution to tell maven to make a consistent build, caching once evaluated version ranges for an artifact, and not asking the repository again?

Solution should not be a repository caching mechanism, as already the request network traffic is completely useless in that case. Repeated request must prevented.

Comment: This is the big drawback of using version ranges. By definition no build reproducibility. The only solution is to use **no version ranges** at all. So using a concrete version number will solve the problem.

Comment: Why "per definition"? Based on the POMs, using only a little logic like repository response caching, it would be possible to evaluate a consistent set of libraries. E.g. _gradle_ can handle it, using the very same dependency definition...

Comment: Between two builds you can have differernt versions of dependencies which in consequence makes a build not reproducible. (If you have a solution for Maven please make a pull request for the maven project).

Comment: My problem is that within the very SAME build, maven is getting 2 different responses from the repository, causing the build to fail. I would be glad if a single build would succeed. Running the same build command again succeeds, if nobody uploads one of the version range referred jars DURING the build.

Comment: Yes of course but in the end using a version range in general makes a build not reproducible...which from my point is the root cause of that so just don't use them...Apart from that how long does your build take? Apart from that shouldn't be those newer versions backward compatible with the previous versions? So this should not break the build? Is there an error message in your build ? Or do you get compile errors ?

Comment: The build runs into an error, as concurrent versions of the same artifact have been detected. Build takes hours due to the massively repeating requests of the same combination of group / name / version-range. Using the latest version is not the problem, as it's compatible. Maven should not repeat the requests during the build. Unfortunately, using versions:resolve is not an option, as the version ranges are also set in the POMs in the repostory, where hundereds of JARs refer to the same lib. That's why we need to use version ranges. Compatibility of these libs is the core concept.

Comment: Furst taking a build is really running hours? The build or the build plus tests? But versions:resolvel-range would solve it...as it resolves to a particular time in point and your build will run without any range which solves your problem. Apart from that I have my doubts that the resolution of those ranges is really you problem related to the time which taken by the build...that sounds there are many other problems which have not solve before...How many modules do you have? How many lines of code? How many tests ? Unit/Integration tests ? How long take the tests to run ?

Comment: Would the versions:resolve-range also impact transient dependencies on the repository? My expectation is that it's only affecting the projects which I currently build, but not pre-built JARs in repositories. We unfortunately rely on having version ranges stored in the repository. Regarding the project I do not have much info, as I am only supporting it, without having access to it. It's without tests.

Comment: It really takes hours, as some artifacts have more than 100 versions, and maven always starts from oldest version. Having nested dependencies again with a huge amount of version, this mechanism starts there recursively, evaluating the same mess over and over again, although it could be easily detected that a newer version exists. That newer version makes deep nested exponential evaluation useless. But maven first looks at the oldest versions.

Comment: Belker You have analyzed the subject very well. What about offering a patch/fix to improve/change that?

Comment: I missed a point: `[1.0.0, 2.0.0)` this says start with `1.0.0` and check if something exist which is greater..but less than `2.0.0`?